# Writing an ImageSource to a file in WinRT

Tags: serialization, bitmap, windows-runtime, imagesource

I want to cache an ImageSource's image to a file, so I can point to it with a URI, but can't find the calls to do it. The problem is that all the example code I can find online is for WPF and the used classes are not present in WinRT.

There are a handful of classes in the Windows.Graphics.Imaging namespace, but as far as I can tell from searching through them and their methods, none of them do what I need.

I have an ImageSource. I want to write the image to a file. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

And ImageSource property is usually a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage) (default when you specify ImageSource with a URI in XAML). In some cases you might want to edit the pixels of your bitmap - that's where you would use a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). Then there are the [SurfaceImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.surfaceimagesource.aspx) and [VirtualSurfaceImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.virtualsurfaceimagesource.aspx) if you want to do DirectX interop to draw some high quality, high performance graphics.

WinRT XAML Toolkit is an open source library that has some [extension methods](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0657c67a93d5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.cs) in the Imaging namespace to help you load and save images. I don't see one that would allow you to save a BitmapImage, though you can use its UriSource property to find out where the image comes from and download it from there, but that sounds like a waste of bandwidth, since you would need to download it twice.

I am not sure what your exact scenario is, but assuming you are downloading an image from the web - you might be best off just downloading it first (e.g. using the [Net.WebFile.SaveAsync()](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0657c67a93d5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Net/WebFile.cs) method and then creating a BitmapImage based on it. On the other hand - when you open a BitmapImage specifying a web address - the image should automatically get cached (e.g. check "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\INetCache\" for images cached by the "News" app), so perhaps it is better to just use web URIs to open the images than managing the cache yourself, which is non-trivial.

Comment: The exact scenario is extracting an embedded song file thumbnail and caching it to a file, so it has a URI to give to MediaControl.

Comment: If what you need is a URI - you could save your file to application's data folder (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder) and use the "ms-appdata:" URI scheme - I think if you create a folder called "Cache" in the local data folder and save a file named "image.png" - the URI would be something like "ms-appdata:///Cache/image.png".

Answer (score 0):

You could also use FFImageLoading (https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/). Or... see its sources to see how it's implemented.

### Features

- Xamarin.iOS (min iOS 7), Xamarin.Android (min Android 4), Xamarin.Forms and Windows (WinRT, UWP) support
- Configurable disk and memory caching
- Deduplication of similar download/load requests
- Error and loading placeholders support
- Images can be automatically downsampled to specified size (less memory usage)
- WebP support
- Image loading Fade-In animations support
- Can retry image downloads (RetryCount, RetryDelay)
- On Android transparency is disabled by default (configurable). Saves 50% of memory
- Transformations support

  - BlurredTransformation
  - CircleTransformation, RoundedTransformation, CornersTransformation
  - ColorSpaceTransformation, GrayscaleTransformation, SepiaTransformation
  - FlipTransformation
  - Supports custom transformations (native platform ITransformation implementations)

It's just as simple as:

```
<ff:FFImage Name="image"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    LoadingPlaceholder="loading.png"
    ErrorPlaceholder="error.png"
    CacheDuration="30"
    RetryCount="3"
    RetryDelay="250"
    DownsampleHeight="300"
    Source="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-600-600-5.jpg">
</ff:FFImage>
```

Sample project here: https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/tree/master/samples/Simple.WinPhone.Sample